# Receiving "failed to query" code 13: Access is denied when using virtualenv -p on my windows system

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have two versions of Python installed on my Windows system. 3.7 is installed in C:\Python37 and 3.8 installed in Python 3.8.

My PATH variables include the Python 3.7 executable.

When I try to run 'virtualenv -p C:\Python38 ProjectFolder' I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: failed to query C:\Python38 with code 13 err: 'Access is denied'
```

This is true if I specify C:\Python37 as well.  Isn't this supposed to create a virutalenv using the specified Python binaries? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add quotation marks around the path.

Comment: Thank you Klaus. I tried that but received the same error.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
virtualenv -p C:\Python38\python.exe ProjectFolder
```

I.e. point `-p` to python executable, not to a directory.

Comment: Thank you this was what I needed!  Sort of.  "ProjectFolder" was meant to be the name of the subfolder to put the project into so the final syntax for me was:

vitrualenv - p C:\Python38\python.exe ProjectFolder

Quotes weren't required because I didn't actually have a space in my folder name.

Comment: Ok, let me fix the answer…

Comment: @phd i have a smilar issue, i have python 3.9 in my server but i need to build a aws lambda python package with python 3.8.i have installed python 3.8 in the server but have not set the path. when Im trying to refer to it with above command it gives me access denied error

Comment: @SithijaPiyumanThewaHettige What is the path to Python 3.8 program?

Comment: installed python 3.8 to a custom location ( D:/python) and used this command virtualenv -p D:/python env

Comment: @SithijaPiyumanThewaHettige Please reread my answer carefully, understand it and follow the advice.